# Anyone have a sort algorithm optimized for very slow write operations?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I need a sorting algorithm which operates on a single, pre-populated array, and which is limited to perform only one type of write operation:

**O**=*Move an item X to index Y. The elements on subsequent positions are shifted 1 position.*

The algorithm must be optimized for the least possible number of operations O. Read operations are infinitely cheaper than write operations. Temporary helper lists are also cheap.

**Edit**: It might be more correct to call it a linked list, because of its behaviour, although the implementation is hidden for me.

**Background:**

The thing is I'm working against a [Google API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/move) which only allows me to perform this operation on their lists. The operation is a web service call. I want to minimize the number of calls. You can assume the sorting program (the client) has a copy of the list in memory before starting, so there is no need to perform read operations against the service - only write. You can of course also do any amount of temporary list actions locally before performing the service calls, including duplicating the list or using existing .NET sort functions.

How do I proceed here? Is there a known algorithm I can use here?

**Failed attempt:**

I have already implemented a dumb algorithm, but it is not optimal for all cases. It works well when the list is like this:

List A = `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1]`

It goes like this:

1. Is list sorted? No
2. Find element that belongs at position 0: "1"
3. Move Element "1" to position 0
4. (New list state A1: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`)
5. Is list sorted? Yes. End

...But when the list is like this, I get into trouble:

List B = `[9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

1. Is list sorted? No
2. Find element that belongs at position 0: "1"
3. Move Element "1" to position 0
4. (New list state B1: `[1,9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`)
5. Is list sorted? No
6. Find element that belongs at position 1: "2"
7. Move Element "2" to position 1
8. (New list state B2: `[1,2,9,3,4,5,6,7,8]`)
9. ...you can see where I'm going here...

Comment: Are you working with an array or a linked list here?  Can you append to the ends without having to shift every other element?  If you can, it looks like a case for looking at the levenshtein distance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: What is the API? Is this an interview question?

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly: you can sort the list online in your program; you just need to issue as few possible web-service calls  to put the list in that same order?

Comment: Is the cost of writing to any position the same ? The number of shifts are different for different positions.

Comment: bdares: Inserting at the end (index Count-1) does not cause shift. Inserting at the beginning (index 0) causes all other elements to shift 1 position "free of charge". edit: I guess that basically means it's a linked list

Comment: maniek: No this is not a interview question. I'm interfacing aginst the Google Tasks API : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/move

Comment: krjampani: yes. The cost is constant

Comment: @bdares: actually, LCS distance is more appropriate since there are no substitutions, but +1 for the idea; see my answer.

Comment: bdares: You're definitely on to something with the Levenshtein distance. Looking at the article I believe it's not a perfect match thuogh. I don't do substitution, I do transportation

Comment: If you want to minimize the number of write operations you might consider using [Cycle Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort). Each value is either written zero times, if it's already in its correct position, or written one time to its correct position.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compute the longest increasing subsequence of the array. Perform a write operation for each element that is not present in the sequence.

**EDIT:** Adding an example

Let the numbers in the input array be `1 3 2 7 4 8 6 5 9`. A longest increasing sequence is `1 2 4 6 9`. When computing this sequence store the indexes of the elements that occur in the sequence. Then it is straightforward to travel through the original array and find the elements not present in the sequence. In this case they are `3 7 8 5`. For each of these elements perform a write operation that places them in the appropriate position. So the sequence of modifications of the array would be:

```
1 2 3 7 4 8 6 5 9 (after writing 3 to appropriate position)
1 2 3 4 8 6 7 5 9 (after writing 7 to appropriate position)
1 2 3 4 6 7 5 8 9 (after writing 8 to appropriate position)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 (after writing 5 to appropriate position)
```

Comment: This is much easier than my solution and runs in O(n lg n) worst-case time (vs. quadratic time) when implemented properly. +1.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example? How do I chose which element is the first to be written, given that there is more than 1 "not in the sequence"?

Comment: @Nilzor: that shouldn't matter as pushing an element takes unit time, right? Otherwise, you can sort the elements that are not in the LIS.

Comment: Ok I see. I'll try to implement this then and get back to you when my unit tests pass :)

Answer (score 2):

Sort the array locally. Keep a copy of the original.

Compute the optimal edit sequence between the original array and the sorted version using [LCS distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem); that's the variant of [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) where substitutions are not allowed. A simplified version of the dynamic programming algorithm for Levenshtein can be used to compute LCS distance. Look at the source code for programs such as [`diff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) to see how the edit sequence can be obtained from the dynamic programming table.

You now have an edit sequence, meaning a list of insertions and deletions to be performed to transform the original array into the sorted version. Perform the insertions. (You can skip the deletions since they'll be performed by your operation O, but be aware that indices into the arrays change because of that, so you'll have to compensate for that.)

Comment: Understanding how diff works is no easy task. Maybe it would be better if he just used diff as a black box, from his program.

Comment: @Eduardo: sure, that's a possibility. I have no idea whether `diff` is available in .NET environments.

Comment: I wish that every time someone left an unexplained downvote, they got struck by lightning.

Comment: This is a great answer and works in the more general setting when you want to convert one string into another with fewest number of insertions. I upvoted.

Comment: @Wug: at least, there should be some function that shows who downvoted a post.

Answer (score 2):

Search for the longest sorted subsequence, and shift each unsorted element into it's correct position.

For your examples:

```
start: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1 (O = 0)
LSS:   2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
step:  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 (O = 1)

start: 9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 (O = 0)
LSS:   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
step:  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 (O = 1)
```

One of mine:

```
start: 9,3,1,7,2,8,5,6,4 (O = 0)
LSS:   1,2,5,6
step:  3,1,7,2,8,5,6,9,4 (O = 1)
LSS:   1,2,5,6,9
step:  1,7,2,3,8,5,6,9,4 (O = 2)
LSS:   1,2,3,5,6,9
step:  1,2,3,8,5,6,7,9,4 (O = 3)
LSS:   1,2,3,5,6,7,9
step:  1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,4 (O = 4)
LSS:   1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9
step:  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 (O = 5)
```

You'll need an algorithm to identify the LSS.  You only need to use it once, after you have it, you can just insert elements into it as you sort.

Pseudocode:

```
function O(oldindex, newindex):
    # removes oldindex from list, shifts elements, inserts at newindex

function lss(list):
    # identifies the LSS of a list and returns it in a cheap temporary list

function insert(index, element, list):
    # inserts specified specified element into specified index in specified list
    # elements at and after specified index are shifted down to make room

function sort(input):
    lss_temp_list = lss(input)                     # get lss of input list

    do until lss == input:
    old = any(index where (input[index] not in lss)# item in input; not in lss

                                                   # getting new index is uglier
    nl = min(X where (X > input[old] and X in lss))# next lowest element in lss
    nh = max(X where (X < input[old] and X in lss))# next highest element in lss

    new = any(index                                # index of next lowest/highest
          where ((input[index + 1] == nl and nl exists)
              or (input[index + 1] == nh and nh exists))

    O(old, new)                                    # list shift

    il = min(index where (lss[index] > input[new]))# index of next lowest in lss
    ih = max(index where (lss[index] < input[new]))# index of next highest in lss
    i = any(X where (X == il or X == (ih + 1)))    # index to insert element
    insert(i, input[new], lss)                     # add new element to lss
    repeat
    return input
```

Apologies for the wonky pseudocode style, I was trying to make it narrow enough to not make the code block need a scroll bar.

Comment: Optimized for fewest number of calls to O but not for shortest total move distance.  I know this is a hypothetical question, but depending on the implementation, total move distance might be more important.